# PST Canada on software development to be used by BC company

Tags: taxes, canada, canada-revenue-agency

A quick question to sole proprietors - if I provide software development services, do I need to charge Provincial Sales Tax (PST) on them (living in BC, companies that I work for are in BC as well).

Comment: Although there's a helpful looking answer below, a broader version of this question that addresses the issue in a range of jurisdictions might be of interest.  For example, I know that in my state consulting services require payment of "sales tax"  (it's actually a gross receipts tax.)  This has surprised some of my friends starting up as 1099 consultants who weren't aware of the tax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to develop custom software for many companies in BC and never charged PST.

In general you must charge PST if you sell software that you own. However there are a few exemptions.

If you develop custom software for individual companies for their exclusive use (and do not resell the software to others) that is exempt.

From https://www2.gov.bc.ca/assets/gov/taxes/sales-taxes/publications/pst-105-software.pdf

[image]

**You still have to charge GST as you are providing software development services.**

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the help!

Comment: Did you still report quarterly even you didn't charge PST?

Comment: I never registered for PST so no. I did collect and report GST however.